# system.out.println statement outside any method in java

Tags: java, program-entry-point

My question is can't we write an output statement outside the main in java? If I enclose it in { } braces then I don't get error, but if I directly write it, I get an error. why so?

```
public class abc 
{ 
   int a=3; 
   int b=0; 
   System.out.println("this statement gives error"); //Error!! 
   {System.out.println("this works fine");} 
   public static void main(String args[]) {

   System.out.println("main"); 
      abc t=new abc();
   }
}
```

I tried writing it in main, it works. Why doesn't it work without a method?

Comment: The `{...}` syntax is actually the same as just putting it in the constructor of the class.

Comment: this means that you need to know some more about the basics of java, if you need any explanation about the basics of java feel free to ask

Comment: I see this question as a valid confusion coming from pattern matching and unintended consequences. Almost all beginning code in Java lessons start with the ubiquitous System.out.println("Hello World!"); without pointing out that public static void main() is not the same as the Main class. 

I remember having this whole thing kind of thrown at us in CS without discussion of the structure. To avoid this false pattern matching, I would suggest naming the class something other than Main.

Answer (score 10):

When you enclose it in braces, you are putting it in an initializer block, which runs when the class is instantiated. No statements except variables declarations/initialization may take place outside of methods or initialization blocks in Java.

Comment: I don't know why people answer the question with again Why question. Why we can't?

Comment: @UnKnown Why can't you what? The answer to a lot of "why" questions is "because that's how the language was designed"

Answer (score 5):

A `Class` can only have attributes or methods.

A [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) is the blueprint from which individual objects are created.

```
    int a=3;   // attributes
    int b=0;   // attributes
    System.out.println("this statement gives error"); //Error!! 

    {System.out.println("this works fine");}  // init block whenever an object is created.
                                              // since it is inside { }
```

Answer (score 4):

`{...}` is called an [instance initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6) . It runs in addition to the constructor each time an instance object is created .

`static{...}` is another type of block that is called [Static Initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) it is when you add a static keyword before { } . This static initializer only runs when the class is first loaded.

So you can write code in these two block and class member functions.

Other than that the only place left is meant for the class data members declaration and initialization.

Answer (score 1):

**Basics/Fundamentals**

Java `Class` contains only member functions and class variables and few other exceptions like instance initliazer, static blocks etc.

You can't just sprinkle executables(like `System.out.println()`) anywhere you wish inside `Class`.

---

**Instance initliazer**

`{...}` in Java is `instance initializer` which gets called whenever an `object` is created. Because it is `instance initializer`, it actually gets called before `constructor`.

You can write `System.out.println()` inside `{...}`  or `instance initializer`.

---

**Static block**

`static{...}` is called `static block` in Java, which contains lines of code which gets called ONLY ONCE when the `class` is loaded by `JVM`.

Again, You can write `System.out.println()` inside `{...}`  or `static block`.

---

**Simple executable example below**

```
public class JavaExample {
    public JavaExample (String name){
        System.out.println("Inside constructor" + name);
    }
    {
        System.out.println("Inside instance initializer");
    }

    static{
        System.out.println("Inside static block");
    }
    //System.out.println("Will give error"); //ERROR

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaExample obj1 = new JavaExample ("obj1");
        JavaExample obj2 = new JavaExample ("obj2");
        System.out.println("Inside the public static void main");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
> Inside static block 
> Inside instance initializer 
> Inside constructor: obj1 
> Inside instance initializer 
> Inside constructor: obj2 
> Inside the public static void main
```

Please note the order of execution.

1. Static block (gets called once when JVM loads Class, hence first of all)
2. Instance initializer (before the call of any object instantiation)
3. Constructor (during object creation/initialization)