# Simple Java Query

Tags: java

Can someone please explain why the following code throws error while compiling?

---

```
  public class demo {

         System.out.println("static block is invoked"); 
    }
```

Why it is not possible to compile a program without `PSVM(String args[])`?

Comment: Because the Java Spec says so

Comment: because it is not in a code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to run anything ,you always need a starting point,

So Java language developers decided to have this main Method as starting point of execution.

and So your code does not compile ,because these statements cannot be directly in class. Only variable declarations are allowed directly inside class,everything else needs to go inside some method or initialization blocks.

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> Why it is not possible to compile a program without PSVM(String
>   args[])?

As JavaSpecification said in [Chapter 12:Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html)

> The Java Virtual Machine starts up by loading a specified class and
>   then invoking the method main in this specified class.

this is why main method is required for Execution.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not inside a block(static block or initializer block) nor in any method.

Do

```
public class demo {

    public static void main(String[] a){

            System.out.println("static block is invoked"); 
           }
        }
```

No statements except variables declarations/initialization may take place outside of methods or initialization blocks in Java.

Also check [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795467/system-out-println-statement-outside-any-method-in-java)

> Why it is not possible to compile a program without PSVM(String
>   args[])?

Because main method is used as entry point by JVM to access properties of class.
So thats why its declared `public` so that it can be accessed from anywhere.Its `static` so that it can direcly be called by className.

Comment: Are you trying to say if something is in `init` or `static block` will also not executed ???

Comment: @NeerajJain when did I say this?

Comment: Initially you mentioned that `because it is not inside main method` , on that point i post the comment , and please Do add init block also in your post