# why can't we add elements to ArrayList outside of the main() method?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class first {

    ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add("Batman");          //it doesn't work
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Why doesn't it allow to use add method outside of main?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [system.out.println statement outside any method in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795467/system-out-println-statement-outside-any-method-in-java)

Comment: That cannot be done simply because the language does not allow it. It *would* work though if you surround that `al.add` line with curly braces. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865069/why-is-this-java-code-in-curly-braces-outside-of-a-method As for the motivations behind requiring curly braces on that second line but not the first line, I don't know.

Comment: @Roman - Adding { ... } around the 2nd line is turning it into an *instance initializer block*.  I can't tell your the definitive design rationale / motivation, but I think this is simply borrowed from C / C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a basic concept of Java or an architecture of Java, you can only declare variables and methods in class. All functionality related work should be done in functions only.

You can refer this link for Class definition, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Answer (score 3):

You're missing brackets.

Try this code:

```
public class first {

    ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
    {
          al.add("Batman");  
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the creators of the Java language came to the conclusions they did, so unfortunately the best answer I can give is: It cannot be done because the Java language (compiler) does not allow you to do it.

What you *can* do is surround that method call in curly braces and then it becomes an [initializer block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

This is a similar question: [Why is this Java code in curly braces ({}) outside of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865069/why-is-this-java-code-in-curly-braces-outside-of-a-method)

Answer (score 1):

A `class` has the following structure: `attributes` (your `arraylist`) followed by `functions` ( like `main()`).

To do any manipulations on an `attribute`, it must be done within a `function`. This is done this way because it was designed this way.

Answer (score 1):

"al" is an instance variable of class "first" and without declaring an object of class "first" you cannot add anything inside even main function.

If you have to add anything outside main function without creating an object of class then that instance must be static and then you can add string by putting it inside curly braces.

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();

{
    al.add("names");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Patterns like *factory method* or *fluent builder* can be very helpful in java if no constructor exists because they allow you to declare, instantiate and initialize your objects in one same expression.

Here are examples for your case :

```
List<String> l = java.util.Arrays.asList("Batman");

ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(java.util.Arrays.asList("Batman"));

ArrayList<String> al = com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList("Batman");
```

The last example uses the [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library. It has factory methods and/or builders for all kind of java collections.

Answer (score 1):

As per Java Architecture you can't write any logical statement outside the method
.