# Understanding a Java syntax error

Tags: java, jar, download

I am rather new to java and I do not understand an error I am getting. Eclipse is not recommending to me how to fix it.

I am getting the following error with my below code:

"Syntax error on token "getChannel", Identifier expected after this token"

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;

public class main {
    URL website = new URL("http://ts.vtggames.net/extras.zip");
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("extras.zip");
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: You have to put statements in a block of some sort, like a method.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795467/system-out-println-statement-outside-any-method-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062481/why-cant-i-do-assignment-outside-a-method

Answer (score 1):

This is a statement:

```
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

It has to go in a block: basically, it has to be in *some* syntactic construct inside the class wrapped in `{}`.

The other lines are variable declarations. These can go outside blocks; this is why the first syntax error is on the `fos.getChannel()` line.

You can put all of the lines in a `main` method, like this:

```
public class main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {  // <-- Add this line
    URL website = new URL("http://ts.vtggames.net/extras.zip");
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("extras.zip");
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
  }  // <-- and this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @AndyTurner mentioned, this isn't proper Java code

- Classes in Java should begin with an uppercase letter
- You should put your main code in a method
- A `public static void main(String[] args)` should be provided to run the class standalone

Comment: "Classes in Java need to begin with an uppercase letter" No they don't. This is mere convention.

Comment: "All executable code needs to be in a method" No, it can be in an initializer block, which is not a method.

Comment: @AndyTurner I realized that as soon I posted it :).

Comment: "A public static void main(String[] args) method must be provided as a runner" Not to compile the class.

Comment: @AndyTurner you're right, should've phrased it better