# Reverse a string in java on repl.it

Tags: java, string, reverse, replit

I need some help with some code. I am trying to reverse a string which is entered by the user. Could someone have some experience with repl.it please help me.

Here is the code that I am using (ignore the first part of the code that already works)

**Main**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        int i = inp.nextInt();
        int o =i+i;
        System.out.println(o);
    }

    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("In:");
    String word = inp.nextLine();
    int counter = word.length();
    for(counter>0){
        System.out.println(word.charAt(counter));
        int counter-1;
    }
}
```

here is the long list of errors that I am getting

```
exit status 1
Main.java:16: error: <identifier> expected    
    System.out.print("In:");   
                    ^    
Main.java:16: error: illegal start of type    
    System.out.print("In:");    
                     ^    
Main.java:19: error: illegal start of type   
    for(counter>0){    
    ^    
Main.java:19: error: <identifier> expected    
    for(counter>0){    
               ^    
Main.java:19: error: ';' expected    
    for(counter>0){    
                ^    
Main.java:19: error: illegal start of type    
    for(counter>0){    
                 ^    
Main.java:19: error: <identifier> expected    
    for(counter>0){    
                  ^    
Main.java:19: error: ';' expected    
    for(counter>0){    
                   ^    
Main.java:20: error: illegal start of type    
      System.out.println(word.charAt(counter));    
            ^    
Main.java:20: error: ';' expected    
      System.out.println(word.charAt(counter));   
                ^    
Main.java:20: error: invalid method declaration; return type required    
      System.out.println(word.charAt(counter));    
                 ^   
Main.java:20: error: <identifier> expected    
      System.out.println(word.charAt(counter));    
                                    ^    
Main.java:20: error: ';' expected    
      System.out.println(word.charAt(counter));    
                                     ^    
Main.java:20: error: illegal start of type    
      System.out.println(word.charAt(counter));   
                                            ^   
Main.java:20: error: <identifier> expected    
      System.out.println(word.charAt(counter));   
                                             ^   
Main.java:21: error: ';' expected    
    int counter-1;    
               ^   
Main.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected  
    }   
    ^    
17 errors
```

Comment: Hi eRrOR SaNs, welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like all the lines with an error are outside of a method. In Java, only variable assignments can be done outside, so `System.out.println()` or `for` loops are invalid. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795467/system-out-println-statement-outside-any-method-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [system.out.println statement outside any method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795467/system-out-println-statement-outside-any-method-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the fixed and final result

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a number");
    int i = inp.nextInt();
    int o =i+i;
    System.out.println(o);
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("In:");
    String word = in.nextLine();
    //write your code below
    int counter = word.length();
    while(counter>0){
      System.out.print(word.charAt(counter-1));
      counter--;
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("In: ");
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder(word).reverse());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason behind this errors that you are putting code outside the `main` method. every code that you want to execute must belong to the method `public static void main`.

this is how to fix it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        int i = inp.nextInt();
        int o =i+i;
        System.out.println(o);

        System.out.print("In:");
        String word = inp.nextLine();
        int counter = word.length();
        for(counter>0){
            System.out.println(word.charAt(counter));
            int counter-1;
        }

    }    
}
```